# Number of unique combinations of 5 photos that are inserted into 10 background images

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm awful in maths. So, can I ask, if I need to add 5 unique photos into 10 unique background images, how many unique combinations could I get? Any online calculator that I could use?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Are you allowed to place more than one photo against the same background image?

Comment: No, only one photo per one background image. Each combination must be unique

Answer (score 0):

You can add $n$ unique photos into $n$ unique background images in $n!=1*2* \cdots *n$ ways. Now, if among the $n$ photos, $m<n$ are undistinguishable (which can be thought to be the case) there must be $n!/m!$ distinct ways.

Comment: Too complicated to me. So what is the answer? Any calculator I could use?

Comment: Is your intention to treat the $m$ missing photos as indistinguishable objects?  If so, that may be difficult for a novice to grasp.

Comment: You’re right, I’m sorry...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 10!/5! = 10*9*8*7*6 = 30,240. Pretty much any regular calculator should do the math. If you want to understand, tell me an I can try and give a deeper explanation below.

Comment: I was hoping there's an online calculator for this. Will these work - https://goodcalculators.com/combinations-permutations-calculator/ https://www.dcode.fr/combinations